# EJB blocking lookup

Tags: java, jboss, ejb

I'm developing a little calculator using EJB technology, in particular JBoss Application Server and Eclipse as IDE.

```
Hashtable ht = new Hashtable();
ht.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "jnp://localhost:1090");
ht.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory");
Context jndiContext = new  InitialContext(ht);
calculator = (FacadeRemote) jndiContext.lookup("Facade");
```

This is a snippet of code which tries to lookup a bean called "Facade", the problem is that lookup method invocation blocks the execution of the program.

Comment: Yes, what did you expect? Is your problem that it's blocking your GUI, e.g., Swing app?

Comment: The problem is that I expect that after lookup I should obtain a reference to a bean, but my application (it's not a graphical application) stuck and the IDE is still responsive.

Answer (score 0):

The Jboss naming service by default runs on port 1099, did you change it to 1090 for a particular reason ?

Also, to further debug this, you could try and suspend the thread where the lookup is occuring, and send us that thread dump.

These are the default jndi properties that jboss is using (they are available automatically to your app if you have the necessary jboss client libraries in your classpath).

```
java.naming.factory.initial=org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory
java.naming.provider.url=jnp://localhost:1099
java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=org.jboss.naming:org.jnp.interfaces
```

Comment: I used a wrong port (1090) and now I use the correct port, 1099.

But now I have another problem:

javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Facade not bound
 at org.jnp.server.NamingServer.getBinding(NamingServer.java:771)
 at org.jnp.server.NamingServer.getBinding(NamingServer.java:779)
 at org.jnp.server.NamingServer.getObject(NamingServer.java:785)
 at org.jnp.server.NamingServer.lookup(NamingServer.java:443)

How can I correctly lookup the bean "Facade" ?

Comment: so the blocking lookup issue is solved by changing the port number ?

Comment: Excuse me, I wrongly typed the comment, so I editet it. Please look at it now, thank you.

Comment: The error in your recent comment is a JDNI naming issue (your EJB not  bound to the name your client code expects). If the blocking lookup issue is solved, I would suggest accepting the answer and create a new question with the complete stack trace and client lookup code.